# Provedor de serviços do Registro.BR

Tags: domínio

Quero me submeter como provedor de serviços no Registro.BR e isso exige que um teste seja feito no ambiente de homologação deles. Estou achando as informações desencontradas, então me restaram algumas dúvidas

1- Eles citam uma aplicação chamada shepp. Pelo que entendi você envia um comando passando algumas parâmetros e recebe um XML como reposta. Entendimento desse shepp é necessário para a realização do teste? Qual a vantagem de utiliza-lo? Li algum colaborador em uma thread do email list dizendo que é totalmente opcional e ele incentiva a utilização do servidor de testes

2- Para ter acesso a esse servidor de teste eu preciso preencher aquele formulário de homologação, é isso? O mesmo formulário vai me gerar as credenciais de teste e mais tarde eu me submeto ao ambiente de homologação?

3- Existe uma biblioteca em C++ chamada libepp-nicbr. Pelo que entendi ela é opcional. O que não é opcional é a utilização de "XML sobre TLS aplicada ao protocolo EPP", certo? Existe alguma vantagem sobre utilizar a biblioteca que eles provem? Eu nao tenho muita experiência com C++, com exceção dos tempos de faculdade. A idéia seria utilizar alguma outra linguagem, como o Ruby, PHP ou  Node para executar um comando dessa biblioteca?

Essa biblioteca não tem documentação, é isso mesmo? Exemplos de respostas eu posso encontrar nesse link, confere? ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/pt-policy-restrictions-espec.txt

Answer (score 2):

1 - O shepp é útil para o teste pois o procedimento de homologação (ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/pt-epp-accreditation-proc.txt) está descrito em sintaxe do shepp, mas se você não vai usar a libepp-nicbr para integração, fazer a homologação com o shepp te dará a falsa impressão de que está tudo pronto do seu lado.

2 - É necessário preencher o formulário de homologação para acesso ao servidor de testes, mas o servidor de testes é o mesmo do ambiente de homologação.

3 - Se você vai utilizar uma outra linguagem, o que faz mais sentido é usar uma biblioteca nativa de EPP dessa linguagem, mas você terá que implementar as extensões específicas do .br (ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/draft-neves-epp-brorg-06.txt e ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/draft-neves-epp-brdomain-05.txt). Uma possibilidade seria pegar esta implementação em PHP que é de um gateway para um plataforma de billing em PHP, e adaptar para o seu uso:
https://github.com/registrobr/whmcs-registrobr-epp

A biblioteca tem sim documentação, é um arquivo doxygen relativo a cada versão que pode ser consultado num browser. Por exemplo, a versão mais recente:
ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/libepp-nicbr-1.15.tar.gz
Tem sua documentação neste arquivo:
ftp://ftp.registro.br/pub/libepp-nicbr/libepp-nicbr-1.15-doxygen.tar.gz

Minha sugestão é olhar quais os casos de uso que seu projeto requer, e quais os casos de uso que a homologação requer. Os que forem necessários para ambos, desenvolver e utilizar tanto na integração quanto para a homologação. Os que forem necessários apenas para homologação, fazer com o shepp ao invés de desenvolver, mas deixar documentado como utilizar o shepp para os casos não implementados.